# OpenGL rolling ball

Tags: opengl-es

I'm writing an OpenGL ES 1.0 Android 2D game. There I want to create a rolling ball but I have no idea how to do this. Of course I can load a ball texture and move it along the x or y axis but the rolling effect is not there. How can I create such an effect? The game is in bird perspective so you are looking from above to the field.

Comment: Can you map the ball texture to a sphere, and then apply transforms on the sphere to give it a rolling effect. For simplicity, a ball rolling down the x axis needs to be rotated about its local y axis, so you can repeatedly translate the sphere to the origin, apply a rotation about the y axis, and then translate it back..

Comment: Why should I use a sphere? I only have a 2D projection and a sphere is aa 3D object. How should I set the Z axis if it is completly ignored by the projection?

Comment: If you can represent a circle in 2D w/ your texture on it, then you can simply rotate the circle by translating it to the origin and then applying a 2D rotation on it. For example, if you want to rotate your polygon by some amount `theta`, then you can use a 2D rotation matrix http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix to rotate your model.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do this sort of animation with texture coordinates mapped to geometry is to use an authoring tool, such as Maya, 3DSMax or Blender.  Blender is free and fantastic.  I highly recommend it.  You will also need some middleware to import the geometry, textures and animations created in Blender.  For this, look into the PowerVR SDK or Ogre3D or Valve tools.